# Sending Variables from one PHP Page to another after DB query

Tags: php, mysql, forms, forward

So I want to make a search form that queries data from a MySQL DB and then feeds the results to another PHP page as in e.g.:

```
url.com/page?var1=dbresult&var2=dbresult2
```

I know how to send the request to mysql and receive the data, but how do i forward this data to the other php script automatically? The issue is that I can't change the second PHP page as it is part of a plugin. So basically I'll need to forward the user upon submission of the form and after the SQL query to the second PHP page, providing the data as shown in the example.

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: What options does the 'other plugin' allow as to where to read its 'input data' from? i.e GET parameters or POST parameters. can we give it a URL to read, or a file, or POST parameters? Providing more details about the 'other page' may assist people that would like to help.

Comment: Thanks, yes the other script reads data via POST parameters. The problem I am having is that I don't know, how I can first read the database and then post the results to the other script. I believe it would require some redirect, with the received data from the SQL DB?

Comment: So far the cleanest for me seems to be to use the PHP function         

header('Location: http://...')

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure what exactly your requirement but this is answer i think you want, you want to append the data which fetch from db into your url-->`url.com/page?var1=dbresult&var2=dbresult2`

so when you fetch data from db, you should add this line in your php code

```
<a href='url.com/page.php?var1=".$dbresult."&var2=".$dbresult2 ." '>click here</a>
```

where $dbresult and $dbresult2 = data fetch from db

Comment: Thanks,Yes, this would work, the problem is, I don't want the user to have to click something. It should automatically redirect the user to the new url.
A solution would be AJAX, and there is a also a PHP redirect command, but all these things seem somewhat dirty to me and I wonder what the correct way would be?

Answer (score 0):

Including action page is the only way recommended by professionals.

In the action page, you have the server side code that process the forms and interact with the DB.
No HTML content is there in the action page.

If the name of a page is `**myform.php**`,
then the action page can be called something like-`**myform_action.php**`[or any other name]

But include `myform_action.php` in `myform.php` like:

```
<?php include 'myform_action.php'; ?>
```

This is not a ultimate solution for this question.
There are many other PHP stuffs works along with this for this requirement.

In case of **redirection**, PHP uses a function **header()**.  The header() function sends a raw HTTP header to a client. Here is the syntax:

```
void header ( string $string [, bool $replace = true [, int $http_response_code ]] )
```

An example:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */
?>
```

OR

Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

```
<html>
<?php
/* This will give an error. Note the output
 * above, which is before the header() call */
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;
?>
```